# Dividing a list of integers into a list of sub-lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

Suppose we have a list of integers for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$

```
Range[1,n]
```

We take the integer in the list that rounds closest to $x=1$, $x=n$, and $x=1+(n-1)/2$.

Next we take the integers that round closest to $x=1+(n-1)/4$, $x=1+3(n-1)/4$ without taking the elements from the previous sub-list.

Then we take integers that round closest to $x=1+(n-1)/8$, $x=1+3(n-1)/8$, $x=1+5(n-1)/8$, $x=1+7(n-1)/8$  without taking the elements from the previous two sub-lists.

We continue taking the integers that round closest to $x=1+(n-1)/2^r$, $x=1+3(n-1)/2^r$,…,$x=1+(2^r-1)(n-1)/2^r$ until we reach an $r\in\mathbb{N}$ where there are no more elements that aren’t in the previous sub-lists.

What would a list of all the sub-lists look like.

For instance, if we have

```
Range[1,6]
```

How would we create a function that takes a list of all the sub-lists of this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: in MMA "Round" rounds to the nearest even integer. The following uses this definition.

We first create a function "get" that returns: "x=1+(n−1)/2r , x=1+3(n−1)/2r,…,x=1+(2r−1)(n−1)/2r". Then we create the first sublist, because it is special. Next we iterate until the original list is exhausted:

```
n = 6; (*length of original list*)
d = Range[1, n];

get[m_, n_] := Module[{},
  Round[1 + (n - 1) Table[2 i - 1, {i, 1, 2^m/2}] / 2^m]
  ]

t = {1, get[1, n][[1]], n};
res = {t};
d = Select[d, ! MemberQ[t, #] &];

sel[m_, d_, n_] := Module[{t},
   t = get[m, n];
   {Select[d, MemberQ[t, #] &], Select[d, ! MemberQ[t, #] &]}
   ];

i = 2; While[d != {}, If[i > 5, Break[]]; {t, d} = sel[i++, d, n]; 
 Print[{d, t}]; AppendTo[res, t]]
res

(* {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 5}, {3}} *)
```