# Dividing list into smaller list using a set of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

Suppose we have the list for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

```
Range[1,n]
```

1. We choose the number in the list where $x=1$, $x=n$ and $x=1+(n-1)/2$ round closest to and the numbers closest to the chosen elements.

For instance, if $n=15$ the elements rounded closest to are boxed, and the elements closest to the chosen elements are underlined.

$$\left\{\boxed{1},\underline2,3,4,5,6,\underline{7},\boxed{8},\underline{9},10,11,12,13,\underline{14},\boxed{15}\right\}\to\left\{1,2,7,8,9,14,15\right\}$$

2. Next we choose the numbers are not in the previous sub-list and round closest to $x=1+(n-1)/4$ and $x=1+3(n-1)/4$ (which are double boxed) and elements closest to the double boxed, underlined and single boxed numbers (which are double-underlined)

$$\require{enclose}\left\{\boxed{1},\underline2,\underline{\underline{3}},\underline{\underline{4}},\boxed{\boxed{5}},\underline{\underline{6}},\underline{7},\boxed{8},\underline{9},\underline{\underline{10}},\underline{\underline{11}},\boxed{\boxed{12}},\underline{\underline{13}},\underline{14},\boxed{15}\right\}\to\left\{3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13\right\}$$

For values of larger $n$, we continue this.  In general, for $r\in\mathbb{N}$, we choose elements that $x=1+(n-1)/2^r$,$x=1+2(n-1)/2^r$...,$x=1+(2^r-1)(n-1)/2^r$ round closest to and aren't in previous iterations; then, choose elements closest to these and those from previous iterations till we have no more elements left.

**Question**

For a larger list such as $n=100$, what would this list look like? For example, for $n=15$, the list of sub-lists would look like.

$$\left\{\left\{1,2,7,8,9,14,15\right\},\left\{3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13\right\}\right\}$$

**Edit:** Here is the code that I have tried

From a [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262459/34171), I know that for each iteration, the boxed numbers can be found using the following:

```
n = 100;(*length of original list*)
d = Range[1, n];
get[m_, n_] := 
  Module[{}, Round[1 + (n - 1) Table[2 i - 1, {i, 1, 2^m/2}]/2^m]];
t = {1, get[1, n][[1]], n};
res = {t};
d = Select[d, ! MemberQ[t, #] &];
sel[m_, d_, n_] := Module[{t}, t = get[m, n];
   {Select[d, MemberQ[t, #] &], Select[d, ! MemberQ[t, #] &]}];
i = 2; While[d != {}, 
 If[i > Length[d], Break[]]; {t, d} = sel[i++, d, n];
 Print[{d, t}]; AppendTo[res, t]]
res
```

Where `res` takes the list of boxed numbers until all values are taken.

Unfortunately, I know little about the code (e.g. `whileloop`,`++`,`break`) to modify it so for each iteration, I can choose numbers closest to the boxed number, as well as the others values from previous iterations.

Comment: In the output,where is `4`?

Comment: @cvgmt My bad. I added it.

Comment: Include code of what you have tried.

Comment: @Edmund I gave code from a previous answer but I'm not sure what else to use.